# TERADATA SQL- how to find a sequence in the data

Tags: sql, teradata

I have a table with the following columns: account, validity_month, amount. The table contains data for half a year: January to June 2019. For each account i'm trying to find sequence in "amount" field - meaning 6 months sequence with similar amount (closed in a range of 10 percent).
In case there is a sequence to the account, ind=1, else 0.

```
account    validity_month   amount    
-------   ---------------   --------
123        201901           1000  
123        201901           500 
123        201902           1002 
123        201902           3000  
123        201903           0
123        201903           1050         
123        201904           1020  
123        201905           1020 
123        201905           555 
123        201906           998
```

In this example there is a match- 6 month with similar amount (1000,1002,1050,1020,1020,998). 
The 10 percent range is calculated according to the value of the previous month.

```
account    validity_month   amount    
-------   ---------------   --------
124        201901           500  
124        201901           0 
124        201902           530 
124        201903           500
124        201903           2000         
124        201904           2000  
124        201905           60 
124        201905           2100
124        201906           2000
```

In this example there is NO a match (3 months with similar amount, and then 3 months with different similar amount). 
In this case, this is the requested output:

```
account    IND    
-------   ------
123          1
124          0
```

Can anyone help?
Thanks!

Comment: What if the sequence is 100, 95, 90, 85, 80, 75?  Each adjacent value is well within 10%.  But they different more than that from the average.

Comment: It is ok. the 10 percent range calculated according to the value of the previous month

Answer (score 0):

If I assume that all values need to be within 10% of each other, then brute force might be the only way:

```
select t1.account,
       (case when t2.account is not null and t3.account is not null and . . .
             then 1 else 0
        end) as flag
from t t1 left join
     t t2
     on t2.account = t1.account and
        t2.amount between t1.amount / 1.1 and t1.amount * 1.1 and
        t2.validity_month = 201902 left join
     t t3
     on t3.account = t1.account and
        t3.amount between t1.amount / 1.1 and t1.amount * 1.1 and
        t3.validity_month = 201903 left join
     . . . 
where t1.validity_month = 201901 
group by t1.account;
```